# character association to mathematical operators

Tags: scheme, operators, character, racket

Is there a way to associate a character to a mathematical operator?

for example, if I can associate the letter "b" as addition then

> (b 2 2)

Output

> 4

Is this possible? If so is there any material or examples I can use as a guide?

Answer (score 8):

It's rather simple, look:

```
(define b +)
(b 2 2)
> 4
```

Now `b` is an alias for `+`. You can use the same idea for creating aliases for any *procedure* you want, with any name (it's not restricted to single-character names). Be aware that it won't work for other special forms; for instance this will produce an error:

```
(define my-and and)
```

Comment: @Mitch you're welcome! If this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it as correct by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Comment: Just to ping the original questioner: when you get a chance, accept Oscar's answer.  It helps in making the Stack Overflow database more useful to others.

Answer (score 6):

The wording is a little off (take this as a friendly note).

In Scheme/Racket the mathematical functions +, -, *, etc. are not keywords as they are in many programming languages. They are simply names.

The expression + evaluates to a value, namely a function that can add numbers.
In order to introduce your own names for values, you can use `define`.

```
(define plus +)
```

Gives the name `plus` to the value resulting from evaluating +.
You can therefore give your own one-letter names, like

```
(define p +)
```

However one-letter names are not characters. Characters are what a string is made of.